# Unix scripting : Writing to another file with “:” is failing

Tags: shell-script, scripting, grep, search

I have below record (and many other such records) in one file

```
9460    xyz            abc (lmn):1027739543798. Taxpayer's identification number (INN): 123. For all IIB. 2016/02/03
```

I need to search for the keyword **IIB**. If it matches, then I need to take that entire record and write to another file.

Below is the code which already exists. This code is not working. Problem with this code is when it takes the full matched
record, it is ignoring the text which falls after ":" and writing to another file.

```
cat keyword.cfg | while read KwdName
do
    echo "KEYWORD:"${KwdName} //This prints IIB
    grep "^${KwdName}\|${KwdName}\|~${KwdName}~\|:${KwdName}$\|:${KwdName}~" ${mainFileWithListOfRecords} | awk -F ":" '{print $1}' >> ${destinationFile}
done
```

So, instead of writing below record to destination file

```
9460    xyz            abc (lmn):1027739543798. Taxpayer's identification number (INN): 123. For all IIB. 2016/02/03
```

It is only writing,

```
9460    xyz            abc (lmn)
```

`cat -vte mainFileWithListOfRecords` gives below output

```
9460^IMEZHPROMBANK^I^ICJSC ;IIB;~ Moscow, (lmn): 1027739543798. Taxpayer's identification number (INN): 123. For all IIB. 2016/02/031#msid=s1448434872350^IC1^I2000/12/28^I2015/11/26^I^I$
```

Comment: `awk -F ":" '{print $1}'`, what were you expecting this to do ?

Comment: I am new. It's already existing code. I would consider removing as even I feel its not required.

Comment: what about `grep IIB  ${mainFileWithListOfRecords} >>  ${destinationFile}`    ?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is to look for the string `IIB` on each line and copy the lines that contain this word to a new file, then the following does that:

```
grep -w IIB inputfile >outputfile
```

The `-w` will force `grep` to look for complete word `IIB` (rather than `IIIB` or `IIB2`).